# What is the fastest and safest way to backup user profile?

Tags: windows-10, backup, user-accounts

After Windows Easy Transfer is gone. I have problems to backup my user accounts profiles. Are there a list of folders that must be copied? 
Any your experiences with transferring user accounts to other locations, other PC and etc.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please share with us what you have researched or attempted so far. The last question, "*recommend me a strategy *", is not a fit here because it solicits opinion and possible debate. We still get the meaning of your question with it removed.

Comment: "After Windows Easy Transfer is gone." - Use the replacement tool.  Microsoft offers a free license to a third-party software package ever since Windows 8.0 was released.  Several questions with suggestions already exist so I won't repeat the information.